# Estou tentando escrever um código em JS para testa o valor de "Muito Bom" a "ruim " em IQA(Indice de qualidade do ar)

Tags: javascript, if

A tarefa consiste no seguinte, medir se o IQA é bom ou ruim. IQA é uma medida de trata do Indice de qualidade do ar. Essa  medida é feita em conjunto com a medida de dois Gases: O3, PM10. Deste modo tem uma tabela para acompanhar se o índice é bom ou ruim.

```
              O3          PM10
Índice       Maximo      Maximo

Muito Bom       59.4        19.4

Bom             119.4       34.4

Medio           179.4       49.4

Fraco           239.4       119.4

Ruim           >239.5      >119.5
```

OBS:O IQA  será determinado pelo pior índice. Quando o O3 for "ruim" o IQA será "ruim". Do mesmo modo quando o PM10 for ruim o IQA será "ruim". O pior índice irá determinar o IQA

Aqui está o meu código. No entanto a minha dúvida é que este código funciona mas ele sempre escreve que está "MUITO BOM" e eu não estou sabendo corrigir isso.

```
   <head>

       <title>CalculoDeIQA</title>

       <meta charset="UTF-8"/> 

   </head>
       <body>
           <h1>Forneça o indice de PM10 e 03 para o cálculo do IQA </h1>
       PM10:<input type="text" name="PM10" id="PM10id">
   <br>
       O3: <input type="text" name="O3" id="O3id" >
   <br>
   <br>
       Enviar: <input type="submit" name="enviar" onclick="calculaIqa()">


        <script language="JavaScript">
        var O3=document.getElementById("O3id");
        var PM10=document.getElementById("PM10id");
        function calculaIqa(){

            if((O3>=239.5) ||  (PM10>=119.5)){

                document.write("IQA ruim ");
            }
            if((O3>=239.4) || (PM10>=119.4)){

                documento.write("IQA fraco");
            }
            if(O3>=179.4||PM10>=49.4){

                document.write("IQA medio");
            }
            if((O3>=119.4)||(PM10>=34.4)){

                document.write("medio");
            }
            if((O3>=59.4) || (PM10>=19.4)){ 
                document.write("IQA  bom");

            }else{
                document.write("IQA Muito Bom");
            }



        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código tem alguns problemas:

O primeiro que não está lendo os valores corretos dos inputs (partindo da ideia que os ids estão corretos) é que faltou `.value` no `document.getElementById`. 
  `document.getElementById` te retorna o elemento, o controle `input`, para ler o valor tem que usar a propriedade value, assim: `document.getElementById("O3id").value`

Segundo, da forma que estão montados os `if`, cada linha é um `if` isolado, mas você quer avaliar assim "ser for isso, senão, se for isso, senão, se for isso, etc".  Para isso, você deve incluir o `else`. Senão, uma condição pode atender ao mesmo tempo mais de um `if` e mostrar mais de um resultado.
Para testar, pense nos valores `O3=90` e `PM10=90`.  Como você está usando o operador "ou" `||`, qualquer uma das condições seria aceita correto?

Pelo seu código, iria mostrar "IQA  bom", porque "O3>=59.4" e também iria mostrar "IQA medio", porque "PM10>=49.4". Por isso precisa usar o `else`.

Veja esse exemplo:

```js
document.getElementById("bt").addEventListener("click", function(){
    calculaIqa();
});

  function calculaIqa() { 

      var O3=(document.getElementById("O3id").value);
      var PM10=(document.getElementById("PM10id").value);


      if((O3>=239.5) || (PM10>=119.5)){

          document.write("IQA ruim ");
      }
      else if((O3>=239.4) || (PM10>=119.4)){

          documento.write("IQA fraco");
      }
      else if(O3>=179.4||PM10>=49.4){

          document.write("IQA medio");
      }
      else if((O3>=119.4)||(PM10>=34.4)){

          document.write("medio");
      }
      else if((O3>=59.4) || (PM10>=19.4)){ 
          document.write("IQA  bom");

      }else{
          document.write("IQA Muito Bom");
      }
 }
```

```html
<p>
  O3: 
  <input type="text" id="O3id" />
</p>
<p>
  PM10: 
  <input type="text" id="PM10id" />
</p>
<p>
    <button id="bt">
    Calcular
    </button>
</p>
```

Por fim, você não mostrou como está executando o `javascript`, mas o mais correto seria ler os valores na hora de executar a *function*, por isso movi os comando que lêem os valores para as variáveis para dentro da *function*, para ter certeza de que, ao executar, vai pegar os valores que estiverem naquele momento.

Comment: Poderia me explicar o que é essa linha no código ?document.getElementById("bt").addEventListener("click", function(){
    calculaIqa();
});

Comment: sim, é pra associar o evento "onclick" no botão com id "bt", por exempoo `<button id="bt" onclick="calculalqa()">`. É que testei o código primeiro no site http://jsfiddle.net/ e lá essa segunda maneira não funciona